# Using recv() to receive chunks of a message

Tags: c, websocket, recv

I am working with WebSockets. I created a small test client which splits the message and then sends it chunk by chunk. For example a message like:

```
PROTOCOL HTTP ACTION UPDATE
```

could be sent as

```
PROTOC
```

as one chunk then

```
OL HTT
```

as another as opposed to send the complete message in one chunk as `PROTOCOL HTTP ACTION UPDATE` which is also a possibility.

So the way I receive the message must reflect that. Currently, I am not sure how to use `recv` when one message will be broken into multiple parts and sent across.

This is what I am trying but I am not sure if this is the correct way. Should I always keep the size of buffer as 200 while receiving? When should I exit the loop?

```
void recv_all(){
            char rec_buffer[200]
            while(1) {
              ssize_t bytes_rec = recv(socket_fd, rec_buffer, sizeof(rec_buffer),0);

            }
}
```

Comment: `recv()` reads arbitrary raw bytes from a socket. It has no concept of WebSockets, or any other protocol. You would need to read the raw bytes and manually reconstruct the WebSocket messages per [RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455), and only then can you reconstruct the chunks of your text data spanning multiple WebSocket messages. Why are you not using a WebSocket library that handles this for you?

Comment: you could try using a web socket parser like https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp

Comment: Also note, `recv()` is a low-level read and in fact, is equivalent to `read()` when the *flags* parameter is `0`. The only difference is then whether a pending datagram is consumed. `recv()` does and `read()` doesn't. So `recv` is simply reading raw bytes from a stream -- which you specify as the first parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(stream) sockets deal with byte streams, not messages.  So they provide a way of getting a stream of bytes between the endpoints and nothing more.  If you want some kind of 'messages' you need to process the byte stream to find the message boudaries and break it up into messages yourself.

The usual way of doing this is with a buffer, such as a C FILE object or a C++ streambuf.  You arrange for bytes to be read from the socket into the buffer and then check to see if there's a complete message in the buffer, usually by looking for a message terminator/boundary marker (such as \r\n or just \n).  If there is, you remove (just) the message from the buffer.

It's quite easy to do in C with POSIX -- you can use `fdopen` to open a FILE with the socket descriptor and then use fgets or getline to read a message up to a newline.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the returned value from the calls to `read()` then use  `strcat()` to glue the parts of the message back together.

Per the OP, the message ends with `\r\n` here is an example of how to read the message as several packets.

```
char *message = malloc( MAX_MSG_LEN +1 );
if( ! message )
{
    perror( "malloc failed" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

// implied else, malloc successful

recv_buf[0] = '\0';
size_t msgLen = 0;
int done = 0;

while( msgLen < MAX_MSG_LEN && !done)
{
    ssize_t byteCount = read( socket_fd, message, MAX_MSG_LEN );

    if( ! byteCount )
    {
        // handle error of sender closing the socket
    }

    else if( byteCount < 0 )
    {
        // handle I/O error
    }

    else
    {
        if( msgLen+byteCount > sizeof( recv_buf ) )
        {
            // handle error of message too long
        }

        else
        {
            message[ byteCount ] = '\0';
            strcat( recv_buf, message );
            msgLen += byteCount;
            if( memcmp( recv_buf[msgLen-2], "\r\n", 2 ) == 0 )
            {
                 done = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
free( message );
```

Note: I have not run the above example, so there may be some debugging to be done.

Comment: The end of message is denoted by `\n\r`. What is the way to detect this with `recv`?

Comment: the function: `recv()` doesn't know anything about the content of the packets.  Rather, after each call to `recv()` use `memcmp()` to compare the end of the currently received packet with `\r\n` and when a match is found, then that packet was the end of the message